# $'\r': command not found with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to complete the instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/aspnet-mssql-compose/.  I am at the last stage:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

I see this error:

```
DotNetCore$ sudo docker-compose up
Starting dotnetcore_db_1 ... done
Starting dotnetcore_web_1 ... done
Attaching to dotnetcore_db_1, dotnetcore_web_1
web_1  | ./entrypoint.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
: invalid optionpoint.sh: line 3: set: -
web_1  | set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
web_1  | ./entrypoint.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
web_1  | ./entrypoint.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file
dotnetcore_web_1 exited with code 2
```

I have spent all day trying to fix this simple error.  Here is the entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
run_cmd="dotnet run --server.urls http://*:80"

until dotnet ef database update; do
>&2 echo "SQL Server is starting up"
sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "SQL Server is up - executing command"
exec $run_cmd
```

So far I have tried:

```
1) Open file using Notepad ++  and select Edit/EOL Conversion.  Unix is greyed out.  This method is descrbed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command-not-found-errors-running-bash-scripts-in-wsl

2) sudo dos2unix {filename}.  This method is desecribed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command-not-found-errors-running-bash-scripts-in-wsl
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: Replace bashism `$'\r'` with more general `$(printf "\r")` that works in `sh`, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entrypoint script has windows linefeeds in it, they aren't valid on a Linux OS and are being parsed as commands to run. Correct that with your editor in the save menu, or use a utility like dos2unix to correct the files.

Once you have removed the linefeeds, you'll need to rebuild your image and then recreate a new container.

Comment: Recreating the containers and images was the step I missed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could also set:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

from: https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/126